# RAID 5 Recovery Reset CMOS and drives show up as 2 Member 4 non-Member

Tags: raid, restore, partition-recovery, raid-5

How do you restore a raid array (not part of your C drive) after resetting BIOS and installing a new C (Windows) drive.

My setup:  (its a LOT of data, i cannot afford to lose it, most of it is irreplaceable)

```
Array 000 3x3TB HDD in raid 5
Array 001 3x3TB HDD in raid 5
    Both raid are on the Intel ICHR10 controller
Single drive for my C drive (on different chipset).
```

CAUSE OF ISSUE:
My C drive failed, and I was having some other problems.  So I removed the C Drive, replaced it with another drive.  Having trouble reading the new drive, so I cleared the CMOS (forgetting that resets the RAID to IDE mode).

Got the new C drive installed and installed Windows on it.  Installed Intel RST and set RAID mode in BIOS.  During bootup of the RAID drives it shows both the RAID arrays "FAILED" and it shows Member Disk(0) and Member Disk(1) and 4x Non Member Disk.

I originally named each array of drives to identify what was on them, and it still shows their proper names, just "Failed" status.

There should be nothing wrong with the data, the drive that failed was my C drive, it was on a different chipset, and not part of the RAID controller.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION??  The only thread I found with any kind of possible solution was this one here:
[Raid 5 Recovery of Partition Table](http://forums.extremeoverclocking.com/showpost.php?p=3329132)

I am a little hesitant to follow those steps as I lack this kind of knowledge to risk losing all my data.  Also one of the steps says to reset disks to non-raid which also concerns me.

Comment: Yes, I have gone into the BIOS and changed it back from IDE to RAID if thats what you mean.  During boot Ctrl-I RST menu for the raid doesnt show any options for enabling, neither does RST in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ReclaiMe RAID Recovery software.  It will tell you which drives go to which array.  Then you can set them as non-member disk, put them back in as member disk, run ReclaiMe again to recover the data.